# How to Remove Two (Related) wp_postmeta Rows?

Tags: post-thumbnails, mysql

I have entries in wp_postmeta like so (shortened for brevity:

> **post_id | meta_key | meta_value**
>
> integer | _thumbnail_id   | integer
>
> integer | rafi     | integer

Now it's easy to select and delete all rows containing _thumb.

Same with rows containing rafi.

What I need to do is delete the rows with a common post_id AND both _thumb and rafi.

The reason is I only want to remove the featured image from posts that have the rafi key set.

I can delete matching _thumbnail_id rows thusly:

> global $wpdb;
>
> $wpdb->query( "
>
> ```
> DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
>
> WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
> ```
>
> " );

But I am not sure how to proceed in terms of doing the proper selecting of the matching rows to set up the deletion.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Would you please elaborate this ***delete the rows with a common post_id AND both _thumb and rafi*** a little bit more ? I mean do you need to delete the rows also which has one `_thumbnail_id` and one `rafi` id, cause that will make the `post_id` appear twice and that makes `post_id` duplicate.

Comment: post_id(s) are duplicated in this table.

meta_id is unique.

So I want to delete, for say post_id 22, the rows that contain rafi and thumb, only if both are present.

I hope that makes things more clear, and not more confusing.

Comment: So the table is actually:

**meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value**

Where meta_id is a unique integer.

Comment: The reason post_id is duplicated in this table is I'm adding a flag to note when I manually added a featured image.

It's part of the "Random Auto Featured Image" plugin I recently published.

This work is part my effort to add an undo capability to the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 5 hours of searching finally I wrote the SQL query and that is-

```
DELETE FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM   (SELECT post_id 
                           FROM   {$wpdb->postmeta} 
                           WHERE  meta_key LIKE '_thumbnail_id' 
                                  AND post_id IN(SELECT post_id 
                                                 WHERE  meta_key LIKE 'rafi')) 
                          AS s)
```

I saw your answer above, but using this kinda `SQL` query for this kinda problem is best practice as well as better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't quite put together the logic to as you showed above, hence my more crude but effective solution.

What you posted is what I wanted to do originally.

Comment: You welcome. If this thing helped you please accept the answer by checking the check sign left of the answer.

Comment: I decided to actually test your code before accepting the answer (what a concept, eh? :-)

First problem. Not sure what to do with it. It looks like a mix of PHP variables and mysql commands ...


Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: You need to run that as SQL command. Go to MySQL command prompt or through Adminer or PHPMyAdmin SQL command window and run it. I tested it at my localhost, worked well. But also need to know if that works on your real data. Replace `{$wpdb->postmeta} ` with postmeta table name, most cases it is `wp_postmeta`.

Comment: Thanks again. I changed the db reference AND added the missing FROM in the second select and voila! It worked.

Comment: `DELETE FROM  wp_postmeta
    WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM   (SELECT post_id 
                           FROM   wp_postmeta 
                           WHERE  meta_key LIKE '_thumbnail_id' 
                                  AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta
                                                 WHERE  meta_key LIKE 'rafi_RandFeat')) 
                          AS s)`

Comment: Clearly having trouble formatting code for comments, but the above is the actual query I ran with success.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. I tested by enabling the "Random Auto Featured Image" plugin, which adds the missing thumbnails and adds the meta key rafi.

I then disable the plugin, and add the following code to functions.php.

Checking the database shows the expected results.

The next step is to incorporate this code into an undo/cleanup function for the plugin.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from wp_postmeta";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach( $result as  $results ) {

  $mid = $results->meta_id;
  $pid = (string)$results->post_id;


  if ($results->meta_key == 'rafi_RandFeat'){
    foreach( $result as  $results1 ) {
            if($results1->meta_key == '_thumbnail_id' && $results1->post_id == $pid){
                $wpdb->query( "
                DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                WHERE meta_id = $mid;
                ");

                $wpdb->query( "
                DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                WHERE meta_id = $results1->meta_id;
                ");

        };
    };
  };
};
```